# String in Postgres; validation of the contents of a string

Tags: database, postgresql, validation, plpgsql

I would like a way to validate a string, it needs to have only letters and uppercase; but I could not find a way to do that.

Comment: Use a regex to validate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for all records where the value 'record' matches only upper or lowercase letters from a-z

```
SELECT value FROM values WHERE value ~ '[A-Za-z]';
```

Comment: Perfect, this solves my problem, but I need it to be just the lyrics; special characters like 'ÉÈÇÊ' and so on can not be in my string

Comment: does [a-zA-Z] return values containing 'ÉÈÇÊ' ?

Comment: shall not contain such characters; once inside the string has one of these; I need a false return.

Comment: Only accept the space character and the following characters in parentheses: (ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 0123456789 ª º - /.,).